# wget changing image name from within page

Tags: wget, html

The image is generated once every `n` minutes, and I want to get each of these to my local directory. I had no success in getting the png-image using the command:

```
wget -r -l1 --no-parent -A.png http://url.com/home/images/
```

since it is blocked by the site, and I cannot use

```
wget http://url.com/home/images/filename.png
```

since the name of the images changes from update to update.

The image is however linked in `http://url.com/home/index.html` and I could get the file name from there. What is a robust way to do this? I know the pattern to search for: it is the only image that is called from the directory `/home/images/`.

Comment: I am successful with your first cmd.
Why weren't you? What is missing, what is wrong with it?

Comment: @polym True, there is nothing wrong with the command, it is just that the website does not allow me to get the images that way. Post edited.

Comment: Can you print the response?

Comment: There is no error, but wget only finds *.html files that are telling me that the page is missing. However, the png-file can be accessed directly through the browser.

Comment: Try my suggestion below. If it still doesn't work, maybe the server is detecting wget requests because of the request header. In this case, you should emulate a browser header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two strategies:

- `index.html` `grep` strategy

It only works, as long there is only one png reference in `index.html`:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget http://url.com/home/images/index.html
LINK=$(cat index.html | grep -zPo 'href=.*.png"')
LINK=${LINK#href=\"}; LINK=${LINK%\"}
wget --no-parent "http://url.com/home/images/$LINK"
rm index.html
```

- Browser emulation by modifying request headers

Examples how to do that are [here](http://www.danielmayor.com/how-to-fake-a-browser-connection-with-wget), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182553/sites-not-accepting-wget-user-agent-header) and [here](http://www.askapache.com/linux/wget-header-trick.html).

Comment: Must try the emulation, too. Thank you.
I did try your script, but I am a bit slow on the syntax, when the png is embedded as "<img src="images/img123456.png" width=600 height=600>", how do I extract its path? It is also not the only png. It is however the only image with that path (for now).

Comment: If its src, then change all `href` to `src` and wget from `http://url.com/home/$LINK` on line 5 instead of `http://url.com/home/images/$LINK`.
I used simple string manipulation, first i remove the `href="` part, second the last `"`.

Comment: Got it working. Added a `| head -1` to the grep so I only got the first (=correct) png. Not the most robust solution, but it is working.

Comment: One more thing. How do I get this to work with cron? `*/5 * * * * /home/user/wget_testbed.sh` does not generate any results.

Comment: Got it working, had to specify the correct destination folder to wget

Comment: Good :). Sorry couldn't answer. Could you post your cron entry? :)